# How to avoid static variable in this code

Tags: c#, optimization, static

I have a class that implements IComparable interface, but my CompareTo function uses one static variable for example class looks like this

```
MyClass : IComparable
{
   CompareTo(MyClass that)
   {
     ....
    double a = SomeOtherClass.staticVariable; 
     ....
   }
}
```

or here is real code

```
  SomeOtherClass
  {
  someMethod()
  {
        foreach (Vertex v in events)
        { 
            sweepLineX = v.VPoint.X; //sweepLineX is static!!!
            ...
            e1.Key = new MyClass(point1, point2); 
        // here i create key of MyClass type which is used to store item in BST
        }
   }
```

Is there any way to avoid using that static variable? I thought about using field of MyClass which would hold the value of staticVariable, but I'll have around 200k instances of MyClass, so it will take space to store one extra double value for it.
The obvious solution would be to insert it as a parameter, but i can't since CompareTo method is from interface, and not my method.

Comment: It mainly depends how you're using it. `const` might work. If you want to write good code, then explain what the variable actually does and we might be able to give tips.

Comment: Are you sure the interface is `IComparer` I guess it is `IComparable`. Both are different.

Comment: If you need to use that variable, what's the problem with using the static one as is?

Comment: I don't see the problem with using the static variable like that, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @KendallFrey variable represents x coordinate of some point, in SomeOtherClass i change it and then call method CompareTo of MyClass.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your code before answering, and more info on why exactly you think having a static there is wrong. But if you need that variable to be static then there's nothing wrong with it being static.

Comment: But how does it get used? Why is it there? It seems to me that a comparison between 2 objects should be deterministic, and not use external state.

Comment: Better-suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since this is working code that is having opinion requested of it...?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, I'm sorry, I edited question.

Comment: @Rik problem is if I wan't to call my algorithm multiple times in the same program, and if they work in parallel, static variable will change.

Comment: In that case, sounds like you want to pass a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @user2764266 I'm with KendallFrey on this one, this is a strange thing to do.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm sorry if I don't understand, but where will I keep value of that parameter later on? Because I want to avoid adding another property to my class, since it has around 200k objects created.

Comment: @NickUdell I'd like to show you my code, but I think it won't help because it has many lines of code, and CompareTo is used here to place an item in BinarySearchTree, but its value depends on that staticVariable

Comment: Could you reduce the code to only the relevant parts? i.e. when you call the CompareTo function and when you update the static variable you're referencing? Then we can get a better idea of the context.

Comment: The clean thing to do is probably to store your variable in each instance of  your comparable class. It might be even cleaner to use `IComparer` instead of `IComparable`, and this would probably reduce the need for so many instances.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid static?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I want to avoid static beacuse my SomeOtherClass can have more than one instance, but different value of staticVariable

Comment: @KendallFrey I think IComparer wouldn't reduce need of so many instances because I have to create instance for every point i work with.
But I guess there isn't another way, either static or variable in each instance. 
I just wanted to make sure there isn't some other way.

Comment: I'm not clear. How can you have `different value of staticVariable` per appdomain can have only one static variable isn't it? If it is instance specific passing the instance in constructor is the preferred option

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) principle. Thats provide you possibility to remove hard link between MyClass and your static class.

1) Pass this constant to method as argument.(Its not much better)

```
MyClass : IComparable
{
    CompareTo(MyClass that, double yourConstant)
    {
        ....
        double a = yourConstant; 
        ....
    }
}
```

2) Pass this variable as Property.
    MyClass : IComparable
    {
        double YourConstant {get; set;}

```
    CompareTo(MyClass that)
    {
        ....
        double a = YourConstant; 
        ....
    }
}
```

3) Pass this variable as constructor parameter.

```
MyClass : IComparable
{
    public MyClass(double constant)
    {
        _yourConstant = constant;
    }

    private double _yourConstant;

    CompareTo(MyClass that)
    {
        ....
        double a = _yourConstant; 
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) is not an option since `CompareTo` belongs to interface. 2) and 3) have the same memory overhead which OP is afraid of :(

Comment: Thanks for answer but we already considered all this solutions in comments, they don't work for me.
Actually first solution would be great, but CompareTo function can't accept two arguments.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You can introduce settings class and pass it instead of passing each parameter from static object. It will be weaker link that static object reference. Memory overhead will present but it will only settings reference.

Comment: @user2764266 you can create the Singletone and pass it to your class as property or constructor parameter.
If you don't need to test MyClass with UnitTests you can keep static field object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a interface.

`IComparable` is just an interface with an

```
int CompareTo(object obj);
```

that returns `0, -1, 1`.

Just create a `IMyComparable` with this function

```
int CompareTo(object obj, int someThingExternal)
```

Derive your classes from `IMyComparable`

**OR**

If you would not mind sacrificing some inheritance. Lets assume `MyClass` wont need to derive from any other class.

```
abstract class MyCompare : IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(Object that)
    {
        return CompareTo(that, YOURSTATICVARIABLE);
    }

    abstract int CompareTo(Object that, int somethingExternal);
}
```

Derive your classes from `MyCompare`.

```
MyClass : MyCompare
```

Comment: Sad that .Net framework won't know about `IMyComparable` and hence it *can't* use `IMyComparable.CompareTo` for comparing :(

Comment: @Sriram: I understand that. But if the OP needs to do a `Sort()` let's say, then that does not make sense in the first place as his `CompareTo` has an external dependency which would give weird results, depending on the value of the external variable when those functions were invoked. The Sort() itself would be unpredictable.